# Как завести прокси на curl?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, curl

Хочу отправить на api.telegram запрос, а хостинг у меня в РФ. Поэтому решил отправлять через прокси. Нагуглил вот это, а оно не работает. Даже ошибок никаких нет. Просто белый экран.

```
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot...&text=привет';
$proxy = 'https://nl-132-134-200.fri-gate0.biz:443';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

Если убрать прокси и запустить с буржуйского хостинга, то всё будет работать. Что не так?

Прокси сам по себе я проверил - работает.

Comment: Настоятельно рекомендую вам ознакомиться со следующими полезными функциями https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php и https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-error.php и https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-errno.php

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -x socks5h://LOGIN:PASSWORD@IP:1080 -L 'https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=ID&text=TEXT'
```